# ExtensionDataObject in DataContract is showing up null

Tags: c#, .net, rest, wcf, datacontract

I had this code working before since a few months and suddenly it stopped working

```
public class UpdateRequestBody : IExtensibleDataObject
{
    public ExtensionDataObject ExtensionData {get; set;}
    [DataMember]
    public bool isAdmin {get; set;}
}
```

The ExtensionDataObject is returning value as null.

The payload I am using is

```
{
    "Hello" : "ABC",
    "isAdmin" : true
}
```

So with the DataExtensionObject,
I should get the value of Hello in the extension class

Surprisingly this code was working before but now it isn't.